# Moment js opening and closing times

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I'm trying to create a customer service opening widget with `moment.js`

Whatever I try it seems that the widget says "closed" when the time is set as a quarter of an hour. 
So it works when I set opening hour till 17.00 CET, but it doesn't work when I set opening hour till 17.15 CET.

So in short: 17.00 works, 16.59 doesn't work.

I just can't see what's wrong with formatting the times.

Any help greatly appreciated!!

```
function customerService(){
  var open = false;
  var time = '09.00-16.59'
  var now = moment();
  var combine = time.split('-')
  var opening_time = moment(combine[0], 'HH')
  var closing_time = moment(combine[1], 'HH')

  if(opening_time.isValid() && closing_time.isValid()){

    console.log(opening_time.isValid() && closing_time.isValid()) // shows always true 

    if(now < closing_time && now > opening_time){

      console.log(now < closing_time && now > opening_time) 
      /* shows true when time is a whole hour, but shows false 
       when time is eg a quarter of an hour. */

       open = true
    }
  }  

 console.log(open)

  $('.opening').each(function(){
    if(open){
      $(this).find('.status:first-child').addClass('open').removeClass('closed')
      $(this).find('.status:nth-child(2)').text( getAjaxTranslation('Open').toLowerCase())
    } else {
      $(this).find('.status:first-child').addClass('closed').removeClass('open')
      $(this).find('.status:nth-child(2)').text( getAjaxTranslation('Closed').toLowerCase())
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found an answer!

First of all it seems that `opening_time` and `closing_time` are not formatted correctly. 
So I changed that to

```
  var opening_time = moment(combine[0], 'hh:mm:ss')
  var closing_time = moment(combine[1], 'hh:mm:ss')
```

Second, the correct way to check if a time is between times is the following:

```
 if(now.isBetween(opening_time, closing_time)){
      open = true
 }
```